# Rails 3.1: path/url to file in public directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got a bunch of files in public/downloads/ directory now how do I get url for them?

P.S. doing just /downloads/xyz.tar.bz2 won't do, because app can be deployed to sub URI.

**UPD** I've found a dead simple solution:

```
  def public_url(file)
    root_url + file
  end
```

Comment: as far as i know, the public directory works pretty much like a static file system. So if your app sits under a folder, as supposed to a domain, you will need to append that to /downloads/

Comment: @Daniel If you're trying to access that URI from something other than the front-end of the Rails app, let us know, because that may also be significant.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think normalocity was almost right here, but it should rather be `root_path` than `Rails.root`.

```
<%= link_to "The file", root_path+"/downloads/test.txt" %>
```

That should match whatever sub-uri your app resides under, and then append the path to the static file to it.

Comment: exactly. i've had root_url, but root_path is imho more logical for this helper. thank you!

Comment: @Frost, I think you might be missing an equals sign right after your first percent symbol. Without that equals sign, nothing will be displayed.

Comment: @Tass Thank you for noticing. I just fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

`link_to "The file", asset_path("downloads/test.txt")`

- `asset_path` Computes the path to asset in public director since Rails 4, I believe
- [`asset_path` documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-asset_path)